# Scrollable div is not scrollable when hovering over image

Tags: html, css

I have this example:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="box">
      <object class="object" data="http://www.marketingvox.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/darpa-balloon.thumbnail.jpg">
      <img class="image" src="http://www.marketingvox.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/darpa-balloon.thumbnail.jpg">
     </object>
   </div>
</div>


.container {
width: 200px;
height: 500px;
overflow: scroll;
background: red;
}

.box {
top: 20px;
left: 20px;
width: 50px;
height: 1000px;
position: relative;    
}

.object {
position: absolute;
}

.image {
top: 50px;
position: absolute;
cursor: pointer;
}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aS972/1/

Hover over the image, and you won't be able to scroll, hover outside of image, and you can scroll. I need to be able to scroll even when hovering over the image.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you using an `<object>` element?

Comment: Also, close your `<img>` tag, this doesn't solve the problem though but add a `/` to the end. `<img .... />`

Comment: I need to use the <object> element. @Mooseman

Comment: Ot is your `object` that is off. Remove that and it works, so its not the hovering over the image for sure.

Comment: Check [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/object.html): `<img>` is not a valid child of an `<object>`. Only `<param>`.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of times with flash video you have to add a `<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />` inside the `<object>` tag to get html to render over it and events (like scrolling) to be fired.

Hopefully that can steer someone to the correct answer.

Comment: This does not solve the problem in chrome. It stays unscrollable.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 2**
I removed the `object` in this fiddle.  It served no purpose in the example, http://jsfiddle.net/aS972/6/.  However, if you must leave it in, use this in the object block like someone else already said.

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
```

**Edit**

Ok, your issue is that your content doesn't even exceed 500px so you can't know if it is scrollable or not.  If you add more content like this http://jsfiddle.net/aS972/5/, it works fine.  Setting the `height` to `auto` caused the `.container` box to expand to the size of `.box`, therefore making it scrollable because it was so tall.

Change your container css to have 'height' as 'auto'.  Setting the '.box' height as much larger seemed to mess it up.

```
.container {
width: 200px;
height: auto; //this changes to auto
overflow: scroll;
background: red;
position: relative; //add relative for good measure.
}
```

Comment: The container is supposed to be scrollable.

Comment: I +1'ed this answer because I saw that it solves the question.  But can you please explain to us this wonder?  What just happened here?

Comment: Although I haven't tested any other browsers, in Chrome, your div still doesn't scroll when hovering over the image.

Comment: Again, the edit does not fix the issue reported at all. The `param` does not seem to work in chrome.

Comment: Bro, the jsfiddle I posted works.  Why use flash anyways?  That is the root of your problem.  Chrome doesn't know if there is something to scroll within the flash object so it tries to scroll within it.  This is why you cannot scroll the page while hovering the image; the object is ontop of it.

Answer (score 0):

The object tag is causing the problem. If you're only displaying an image inside of the object, why not just use an image tag?

http://jsfiddle.net/bSaBm/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <img class="image" src="http://www.marketingvox.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/darpa-balloon.thumbnail.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The author of the question already reported that he needs the object tag. This is ignoring the problem, not solving it and has been suggested many times already.

Comment: @Tikkes The author has yet to give a reason WHY he is using the object tag. Within the code he has provided, the object tag serves no purpose. Until the author gives a rational reason for using it, this is a valid answer.

Comment: And the fact that the author set the data attribute to an image without specifying a type, AND included an img tag inside of the object does not give credibilty to his solution.